# regex with XML tags

Tags: xml, regex, parsing, boost, tags

I currently work on an XML parser, and I need to use regex to get all my tags to put them in a tree.

My file looks like

```
<block1>
   <tag1>
       <subtag1>a</subtag1>
       <subtag2>b</subtag2>
   </tag1>
   <tag2>
       <subtag3>c</subtag3>
       <subtag4>d</subtag4>
   </tag2>
</block1>
```

I would like my regex to match with

```
<block1>
<tag1>
<subtag1>
<subtag2>
<tag2>
<subtag3>
<subtag4>
```

To avoid getting the end tags I escaped the "/" and it works quite well.

My last problem is that I get the whole single-line tags because the first "<" goes with the last ">"...

I am using

```
boost::regex r("(<[^/].*>)");
```

Thanks in advance, 
dubill_a

Comment: Please for the love of something: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags

Comment: Use a negated character class: `<[^/][^>]*>`

Comment: I am aware that regex isn't a good solution to parse XML code, but it is for educational purpose, and I would like to use it for my project.

Comment: Casimir et Hippolyte : I need to get the single-line tags, but just the start tag "<subtagX>", with my old regex, it takes "<subtagX>value</subtagX>"

Comment: Use .*? (lazy match) instead of .* (greedy match). It will get you the shortest match possible.

Comment: @dubill_a You have a problem of greediness. `.*>` will match everything until the last `>`, it's kind of working for you since `.` doesn't match newlines by default. So you have two solutions: use the solution by Casimir et Hippolyte or use an ungreedy pattern `<[^/].*?>`

Comment: @HamZa Thanks, the ungreedy pattern     (<[^/].*?>) works perfectly fine !

Comment: @dubill_a The best advice you've gotten is the first comment on this question. The `>` character is completely valid **as is** in an attribute value. [It does not need escaping.](http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-xml/#syntax) For instance, this is fine `<tag1 foo=">">blah</tag1>`. For the suggested regexps to work, you need to be 100% certain that you will **always** be processing data that cannot have `>` in attributes.

Comment: @Louis As it will be my own files, with my own XML code, it won't have ">" in the data.
Btw, thanks for your help

Answer (score 0):

```
/(<\w+>).*?/
```

[DEMO / EXPLANATION](http://regex101.com/r/fM1wI5)

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes.

Comment: The link was posted by me and it includes everything the SO needs to understand the answer.